# How can I join data to my table that isn't available for everyone without losing results?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, join, amazon-athena, ansi-sql

I have a main table, Table 1, that includes columns for student ID and some other info. There is also Table 2 which includes columns for student ID, survey question, and response.

Essentially, I want to append Table 2 to Table 1, but:

- I only want to bring in the responses for the "Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher?" survey question.
- This question was not asked to students before 04/01/23.
- For those who were not asked this question, I'd like for their row to just have a null after appending the tables.

Table 1 Example:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/01/23 |
| 2 | 03/05/23 |
| 3 | 04/10/23 |
| 4 | 04/12/23 |
| 5 | 04/21/23 |

Table 2 Example:

| ID | Date | Question | Response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/01/23 | What grade are you in? | 9 |
| 2 | 03/05/23 | What grade are you in? | 10 |
| 3 | 04/10/23 | What grade are you in? | 11 |
| 3 | 04/10/23 | Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher? | Yes |
| 4 | 04/12/23 | What grade are you in? | 9 |
| 4 | 04/12/23 | Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher? | Yes |
| 5 | 04/21/23 | What grade are you in? | 11 |
| 5 | 04/21/23 | Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher? | No |

Example Desired Output:

| ID | Date | Question | Response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/01/23 | Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher? | null |
| 2 | 03/05/23 | Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher? | null |
| 3 | 04/10/23 | Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher? | Yes |
| 4 | 04/12/23 | Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher? | Yes |
| 5 | 04/21/23 | Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher? | No |

How can I extract this question only into my results without excluding the students who were not asked it? If I add a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.Question, t2.Response
FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.Question IN ('Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher?')
```

Then it will exclude students 1 and 2. If I don't add the WHERE clause, then it will pull in all of the survey questions that, in my real data set, will generate 100+ rows per student which leaves me with too large a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `WHERE` add that condition to the ON-Clause e.g.

```
SELECT T1.*, t2.Question, t2.Response
FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN @Table_2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.Question = ('Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher?')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there just use

```
SELECT t1.*, IFNULL(t2.Question,'Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher?'), t2.Response
FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
AND t2.Question IN ('Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher?')
ORDER BY t1.`ID`
```

You were using `WHERE`

```
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
wHERE t2.Question IN ('Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher?')
```

which makes the `LEFT JOIN` pointless, instead, use the second case `t2.Question IN ('Did you receive a GPA of 3.0 or higher?')` within the `ON` clause which will join your data accordingly.